# Brunch with html

Tags: html, brunch

Brunch works with almost the all template languages and has plugins for them, but I could't work with vanilla HTML. I just want that on every build brunch just copy my html files(wherever they are located) and paste under that appropriate location on public folder. I don't want to use jade, handlebars or whatever I just want to copy clean HTML files without any modification. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Put them in the `assets` folder like so:

```
app
  assets
     something.html
```

All files in the `assets` folder simply get copied.

That being said, unless your doing a single page website or don't plan on updating the HTML very often, it seems less than ideal to not use a template language if for nothing else than to avoid repeating yourself.

Also, note that you can use something like [jaded-brunch](https://github.com/monokrome/jaded-brunch), to have the files compile to static html files rather than JS. This is rather nice when you want the ease of working with HTML files server-side and still enjoy the benefits of using a template engine for development.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pages-brunch) exactly for your use-case, which will compile, validate and minify your HTML templates located outside of assets directory, which is a must if you're working with templates in a folders-by-feature structure. The plugin also provides a default optimization, ready to be used in production environment.